# tellg() fails in text mode (no newlines involved)

Tags: c++, ifstream

As I understand using `tellg` and `seekg` in text mode can be surprising because of newlines, but i get some strange result without newlines. I have the following code:

```
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    ifstream file("test.txt");

    char a;
    file >> a;

    ifstream::streampos curPos = file.tellg(); // _Fpos = 1
    ifstream::streampos endPos = file.seekg(0, ios::end).tellg(); // _Fpos = 5
    ifstream::streampos testPos = file.seekg(curPos).tellg(); // _Fpos = 1

    file.putback(a);

    testPos = file.tellg(); // _Fpos = -511 in text mode, 
                            // _Fpos = 0 in binary mode
}
```

The text.txt content:

```
0 1 2
```

The last `tellg` returns the wrong result if the file is opened in text mode. If I try to `seekg` to this position it spoils the file stream. I am doing something wrong or is it some kind of a bug?

I am using VS2010, Win 7 64-bit.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you get the same behaviour if you read two characters from the stream before putting one back?

Comment: Exactly what result do you get, and what do you expect? [I'm slightly worried that you are actually expecting something different from what you actually get]

Comment: @paddy no, with two chars it's ok

Comment: @MatsPetersson I get -511 while expecting to get 0 (as it works in binary mode)